# How do I get a specific field in Django query?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to query only a specific field in Django model. After some searching, I figured out that I need to use `only()`. However I need to use `filter(authuser=request.user)` as well. How do I make it possible? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain refinements together, since that returns another QuerySet.

Lets say the model is User, and the field is name.

```
User.objects.filter(authuser=request.user) \
.only('name')
```

You can pass other fields to `.only()`, they just need to be comma separated.

Comment: Oh, what is the backslash in the first line?

Comment: It tells python to extend the current logical line (the instruction) into the next physical line. So you can type multiple lines (putting a backslash at the end of the line) and python will execute it as one logical line!